# the name 'InvokeRequired' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I'm using a method in most of my forms and I want to create this method in a class and then call for it.

this is the method :

```
    using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace GestionBib
{
    class MyClass
    {
    public void InfoLabel(string value)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new Action<string>(InfoLabel), new object[] { value });
                return;
            }
            barStaticItem3.Caption = value;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(6000) { Enabled = true };
                timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    this.InfoLabel(string.Empty);
                    timer.Dispose();
                };
            }

        }
}


}
```

The problem is that when I create this method in a class it gives me these errors:

***Error 1:***

> the name 'InvokeRequired' does not exist in the current context

***Error 2:***

> 'GestionBib.MyClass' does not contain a definition for 'Invoke' and no
>   extension method 'Invoke' accepting a first argument of type
>   'GestionBib.MyClass' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Well, what does your type hierarchy look like? Does `MyClass` actually derive from System.Windows.Forms.Form?

Comment: If it's a method, you need to use () to invoke it -

Comment: @FionaT: brackets won't help him.

Comment: Alright.. see the modifications I made to my post

Answer (score 1):

Simply put your class does not declare either `Invoke` method nor `InvokeRequired`. You need to implement them somehow or derive your class form type that derives form `Control` (`Form` for instance).